# Http 502 Bad Gateway error when accessing a web service

Tags: web-services, proxy, iis-7.5

I have a asp.net 4.0 web site and I'm using some external web services to retrieve some data that I display.

I have created proxies for those web services using the wsdl tool. I'm setting an url and I'm setting PreAuthenticate = true and Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredentials(userName, password) on the web service.

I get an exception when I try to use the web service method on a remote server. The System.Net.WebException is. "The request failed with HTTP status 502: Proxy Error ( No data record is available.  )."

This exception only occurs when I have set my VS 2010 to use my local IIS Web Server (IIS 7.5). When I set VS 2010 to use the VS Development Server there is no trouble at all using the same web service method. I have turned on and off proxy settings in IE to see if that was the case, but no difference there.

I could really need some help here to solve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: any final solution about it?

Answer (score 4):

Seems the problem was the Process Model setting (in IIS 7.5)!
The Identity had to be set to Network Service and not ApplicationPoolIdentity which is the default setting.