# WebService Call from .net C# getting error : (502) Bad Gateway

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

Trying to call WebServices from C# and getting below error:

```
System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway
```

Code:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://xxxxx/cgi/webservice.pl?function=get_latest_ts_values&site_list=130105B&datasource=AT&varfrom=10.00&varto=10.00&lookback=60&format=csv");
        request.Method = "GET";
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream() )
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

But works fine when i use Postman or just copy url in browser and also works fine with below python code:

```
import requests

dataload = {}
dataurl = "https://xxxxx/cgi/webservice.pl?function=get_latest_ts_values&site_list=130105B&datasource=AT&varfrom=10.00&varto=10.00&lookback=60"
headers = {}
response = requests.request("GET", dataurl, headers=headers, data=dataload)
for dataresp in response:
    print(dataresp)
```

What am I doing wrong with C# code?

Comment: 502 is a 5xx error (server error), which alludes to the fact that this is probably a problem of the server not the client.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957915/http-502-bad-gateway-error-when-accessing-a-web-service

Answer (score 0):

The uri for the WebRequest has the query parameter `&format=csv`. Maybe this is why you are getting a 502. The Python request is missing that query parameter. Did you try the WebRequest by removing that part?

Comment: Did you try using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse? Maybe worth a try? It works the same way as WebRequest and WebResponse.

Comment: I'm intrigued now. How about using Create(Uri) instead Create(String)? I highly doubt it is the way the request is formatted.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.create?view=net-5.0#System_Net_WebRequest_Create_System_Uri_

Answer (score 0):

Could be incorrect content type or user agent having the wrong information. Postman could be setting these values without your knowledge. Might try in the exception seeing if there is a a response stream and read it through a streamreader to see if there is any more information you're not seeing to point you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using RestSharp and it works fine. (https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp)

```
 string Uri = "https://xxxx/cgi/webservice.pl?xxxx";
 var client = new RestSharp.RestClient(Uri);
 client.Timeout = -1;
 var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
 IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
 Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```